# Adding the name of a passenger on an Indian Railways ticket

Tags: trains, tickets, india

I booked a ticket for my family online, but when I was filling the form I forgot to give details of my niece - her age is less than 1 year old.  Is it necessary to provide the details, and if yes, than kindly tell me where it is possible and how.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not necessary and practically it won't create any problem while travelling. These details can be important while applying for claiming some kind of travel insurance etc.